# How can I place a 'favorites' icon on a tab using Infragistics XamTabControl?

Tags: wpf, xaml, infragistics

I want to be able to allow a user to set a module as a Favorite by toggling a star icon that is placed on each tab.  Is this possible using Infragistics XamTabs?

Answer (score 1):

The technique you want to use is to template the tab header.  You should create a style that targets the TabItemEx and provide a HeaderTemplate.

In my sample I added a Radio Button and an Image to the header which are bound to an IsFavorite property in my viewmodel causing the image to be visible when the radio button is checked.  The VisConverter converter is being used to toggle the visibility property of the image.

See more details and my sample here.
http://community.infragistics.com/forums/p/67815/344088.aspx#344088